# Graph-like data editor tool?

Tags: charts

Is there any unified editor program for creating, mainpulating and visualizing graphs, trees... or maybe any custom **structured** data. The accent is on editing, not visualization, i.e. not a drawing program, but editor with various automatic manipulation tools.

By graphs, I mean any basic type: (uni)directed, (un)weighted...

Something like MS Excel for graphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GraphViz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz)

> dotty
>   dotty is a customizable graph editor. Its main components are a programmable viewer (lefty) and graph layout generators (dot and neato).
>
> lefty
>   lefty is a two-view graphics editor for technical pictures.

Answer (score 1):

[NodeXL: Network Overview, Discovery and Exploration for Excel](http://nodexl.codeplex.com/) seems like it would suit you exactly.
*Disclaimer: I am an advisor on the NodeXL project.*

NodeXL is an Excel 2007/2010 template for graph analysis, divided into two halves shown in the screenshot below. The left side is the Excel workbook that lets you easily import and edit your network, and the right visualization side shows various graph drawings. It makes it very easy to edit and visualize graphs, including adding any attributes for nodes or edges. Nodes and edges can be filtered by their attributes, or have their color, size, shape, or opacity set based on the attribute values. It also has options for directed or undirected graphs.

[image: Sample NodeXL screenshot showing the Vertex worksheet on the left and node-link diagram on the right.]